# Excel VBA: Effect of called macro on other called macros

Tags: vba, excel, call

EDIT: Since my question turned out to be unclear, I have edited this post.

This is a theoretical question, not a coding question. Let's use one hypothetical example: I run macro X. Within this macro X, I call macro Y (e.g. it turns off the screen updating). Then we are back to macro X. If I call another one, say macro Z, will screen updating be turned off when it runs the code of macro Z, too? My basic question is how a called macro affects other called macros. Hope it is clearer now!

Kind regards,
Marco

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: `Call 1` is no valid syntax. Compile Error should occur. Please read [mcve] and provide a full working example that shows your issue and include `DefGlobal` too.

Comment: Global means for the entire project in which defined. You would want once at the start if only about declarations/initializing (we would need to see the contents of this). Indenting in the above is incorrect and Call keyword is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I know that 1,2,3,etc. are no valid names for macros - I used them as a placebo for the real names of the macros (privacy). The entire macro is valid and works. The only thing I am wondering is that if something is defined in DefGlobal (let's say a variable which contains a workbook name), will this variable be available not only for Macro X, but also for all the other ones which are called during the Macro X execution (Call 1,2,3,etc.)?

Comment: Btw, the indent only implies the macro level, sorry for the confusion. So when No. 1 is called, then it calls DefGlobal and No.2. Then it returns back to Macro X to Call No. 3. Within No.3, it calls DefGlobal again and No.4. Within No. 4, it calls DefGlobal again.

Comment: Your screen updating example should be simple enough to test. Set up an inner macro that alters the sheet, have an outer macro control the screen updating, then step through with F8 and watch.

Comment: For this case, it works. I was just hoping to get a general answer because I dont wanna mess up the current macro too much. Thanks!

Comment: @QHarr screenupdating is always on when debugging.

Comment: @Rory I did not know that! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your specific question, `Screenupdating` will remain turned off until it is either explicitly turned back on, or **all** the code finishes.

Comment: This *does* mean that if (for whatever reason) you are calling a macro via `Application.OnTime` it will turn `ScreenUpdating` on before running the macro.